# Issue Passing Values From One View Controller To Another

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to take the text that is typed into UITextFields in one view, and pass those values into a different View Controller when a button is pressed.  In the first view controller (CreateViewController) I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
@class ThePreviewViewController;
@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker2;
    ThePreviewViewController *_thePreview;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *toName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *fromName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *issue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ThePreviewViewController *thePreview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *expire;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *loveMessage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *gift;
-(IBAction)build;
@end
```

The implementation file is:

```
#import "ThePreviewViewController.h"
@implementation CreateViewController
@synthesize toName, fromName, gift, loveMessage, issue, expire, datePicker, datePicker2;
@synthesize thePreview = _thePreview;

-(IBAction)preview {
    if (_thePreview == nil) {
        self.thePreview = [[ThePreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThePreviewViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;
    }
    _thePreview.issue.text = issue.text;
    _thePreview.gift.text = gift.text;
    _thePreview.expire.text = expire.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_thePreview animated:YES];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

However, after I connect all the outlets, the labels in ThePreviewViewController stay at null.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is due to an issue which has been discussed here before: when you instantiate your `ThePreviewViewController` its UIKit instances are not yet available to have their properties set.

The solution is to create and set `NSString` properties on your `ThePreviewViewController` (or more compactly use an NSDictionary) which then use, in its `ViewWillAppear` event handler to set the properties of its UIKit elements.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the preview IBAction in CreateViewController to just push ThePreviewViewController, and in viewWillAppear set it up like `CreateViewController *creation = [[CreateViewController alloc]init];
    gift.text = creation.gift.text;
    issue.text = creation.issue.text;
    expire.text = creation.expire.text;` but it still came back null.

Comment: @user717452, you should edit your question to show what code you're using now. Make sure that you show in what methods and in which controllers the code snippets are located.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting UITextField text in **ThePreview VC**, you should set a NSString property. This is because the UITextField might not have been loaded yet and **_thePreview.issue.text = issue.text**, will have no effect, since **_thePreview.issue** has still not been created. So create a property (eg. NSString *issueString) in your **ThePreview VC** and then set that property as **_thePreview.issueString = issue.text** in your **CreateViewController**, and then finally in your **ThePreview VC** set your textField text in your **viewDidLoad** method using **self.issue.text = self.issueString**;

Hope this helps.